# What is the gl_NormalMatrix and gl_ModelViewMatrix in shaders?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glsl

A lot of google searches make the assumption that you a basic knowledge of what these matrices represent, while i do not.

I have knowledge of vectors and matrices and their operations.

I want to refer to the most simple shader code that i cannot understand, putting normals and vertices in eye-space:

```
//vertex shader
varying vec4 color;
varying vec3 N;
varying vec3 v;
void main(void)
{

    v = vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex);
    N = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);

    color = gl_Color;

    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

My questions:

(i) As the vertex shader loops through each vertex, does the gl_ModelViewMatrix change with every vertex loop? Or does the gl_ModelViewMatrix remain constant throughout each vertex iteration and can transform any vertex into eye space?

(ii) Similar to my first question, but what information does the gl_NormalMatrix hold? Does it hold information on every normal in the scene and thats how it can transform the current vertex's normal that comes into the vertex shader into eye space? Or does the matrix change as each vertex comes into the vertex shader and thats how it can transform the current vertex's normal that comes into the vertex shader into eye space?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both specified matrices are `uniform`s. Uniform values are constants, they don't change between vertices (as opposed to `varying` variables, which change for each fragment, and `attribute` - for each vertex).

`gl_ModelViewMatrix` is pre-defined uniform variable set from `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix (affected by `glLoadIdentity`, `glTranslate,` `glRotate`, `glScale` or `glLoadMatrix`).

`gl_NormalMatrix` is `transpose(inverse(gl_ModelViewMatrix))`, which is the same matrix but with inverted scale factors. Good explanation of this technique could be found at http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tut09%20Normal%20Transformation.html

Please note that this pre-defined uniforms are deprecated in newer versions of OpenGL (and matrix manipulation functions are deprecated too).

Comment: That is surprisingly well said, thank you. By deprecated, do you mean i should just be sending the ModelView and other matrices uniforms myself in code to the shader? If so, what is the difference instead of them being automatically sent as pre-defined uniforms?

Comment: No noticeable difference. This uniforms just unavailable if you request GL 4+ core profile (should still be present in compatibility profile), or in OpenGL ES2+.

Comment: I'd like to add that `gl_NormalMatrix` is defined as `mat3`, and it is the transpose of the inverse of the upper 3x3 submatrix of the modelview matrix.